# allowing single charactor domain with regex c#

Tags: c#, regex

hey guys i am new to regex and i need little help :)

```
^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$
```

above is my regex pattern to match email in c# mvc textbox, but when i tried to input email like abc@q.com it is not allowing me to do so.

what kind of modifications i should do to this regex patter to allow single charactor domain?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like you have escaped the backslashes where you should not have, e.g.:

```
^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@((?=[0-9a-zA-Z])[-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$
```

Note, however, that *correctly* validating a mail address with a regex is not as trivial as your expression.

Comment: i have used \\ to escape "\" charector if i don't use it i have to use "@" before the whole regex string and it is going to be equal weather i use "\\" or i use @ before the regex string

Comment: and yes this expression requires at least two characters in the domain part that's why i have asked question :)

Comment: @DhavalPankhaniya You're mixing up different things. The need to escape \ comes from C#, not from the regex. Therefore, as long as you post the regex alone, you must not put in double \\ or it will change the meaning of the regex! Also, instead of just downvoting, have you tried my regex? It does match single characters...

Comment: yes i have tried your regex but doesn't work :( and also i have modified my question.

Comment: @DhavalPankhaniya What do you mean "it does not work"? https://regex101.com/r/76AucU/1

Comment: works like charm :) thanks. may b i was making mistake previously.